# How to disable input filed using tailwind css and react conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-css

Hello Dev Community i am here with another issue can need your help.

i want to disable input field based on the Boolean state if the state is true then the input filed should be disable else it can be editable.

i have state variable isTrue which can be eithe true or false and here is the code

```
export function InputFiled(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        className="py-2 pl-3 rounded-[14px] border-[1.3px] border-red-500"
        placeholder={"Name"}
        onChange={(e) => props.setData(e.target.value)}
        value={props.data}
        {...(!props.isTrue && "disabled")}
        // here (below) it works fine but it is permanently disabled option
        //   disabled
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

The solution of this which i got form the attached ([Conditional disabling of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463507/conditional-disabling-of-button)) question is:

```
export function InputFiled(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        className="py-2 pl-3 rounded-[14px] border-[1.3px] border-red-500"
        placeholder={"Name"}
        onChange={(e) => props.setData(e.target.value)}
        value={props.data}
        disabled={props.isTrue? true : false}
        />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set additional `tailwind` css classes based on this state or `prop` which you want to baseline.

```
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
//inside render
<input type='button' 
 onClick={(e)=> setDisabled(!isDisabled)}
 disabled={isDisabled}
>
```

Comment: dear it is not a button

Comment: if normal text box , then as I mentioned you need to use conditional class of tailwind e.g. 

    <input className={`${state} ? 'disabled:opacity-75' : '' `} />

Comment: dear i got the answer from the similar question link suggested by the platform. 
and the solution your are suggesting is just the styling property not the exactly disabling of the filed